# Parameters types mismatch in proxy generated class for WCF Service

Tags: vb.net, wcf, proxy, datatables, type-mismatch

I'm using VB.net in VS2012 with .net framework 4.0

**I've 4 projects:**

1. DataAccessTier (contains Dataset definition)
2. DataEntityTier (strongly typed tableadapters for dataset)
3. DataService    (WCF service that expose contracts)
4. Client (Use generated proxy class to consume service)

I define contracts in service

```
Function SetCustomers(data As CustomersDataTable) As Integer Implements IService.SetCustomers
    Using a = New CustomersTableAdapter
        SetCustomers = a.Update(data)
    End Using
End Function


Function SetOrders(data As OrdersDataTable) As OrdersDataTable Implements Service.SetOrders
    Using a = New OrdersTableAdapter
        a.Update(data)

    End Using
    Return data
End Function


Public Function GetOrders() As OrdersDataTable Implements IService.GetOrders
    Return (New OrdersTableAdapter).GetData()
End Function
```

Datatables and Tableadapters objects refers to DataEntityTier assembly. All Data* project have IData namespace.

Ok then I add reference to the service in the client, **with reuse types**. The proxy class is generated and here is the result:

```
   <System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://tempuri.org/IService/SetCustomers", ReplyAction:="http://tempuri.org/IService/SetCustomersResponse")>  _
    Function SetCustomers(ByVal data As IData.DS.CustomersDataTable) As Integer


   <System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetOrders", ReplyAction:="http://tempuri.org/IService/GetOrdersResponse")>  _
    Function GetOrders() As IData.DS.OrdersDataTable


    <System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action:="http://tempuri.org/IService/SetOrders", ReplyAction:="http://tempuri.org/IService/SetOrdersResponse")>  _
    Function SetOrders(ByVal data As IData.DS.CustomersDataTable) As IData.DS.OrdersDataTable
```

Everything is fine expect for **SetOrders**(data As IData.DS.**CustomersDataTable**)!
This issue is in every method i use with a typed datatable as a parameter, the proxy use always CustomersDataTable.

But when i return it from a contract it serialize correct as in the GetOrders function.

If i correct the proxy class manually, it work fine but when i update service reference i lose the changes.

PS. If i remove reuse types every function return an object xxxResponse (es GetOrdersResponse) and I don't know how to use it :S

Answer (score 0):

I not solved the problem, but I've used a "workaround". I've create my own proxy (in a separate assembly so it can be reused in other projects). A bit more work, but a way more clean and thin

```
Public Class ServiceProxy
Inherits ClientBase(Of IService)
Implements IService

Public Function SetCustomers(data As DS.CustomersDataTable) As DS.CustomersDataTable Implements IService.SetCustomers
    Return Channel.SetCustomers(data)
End Function
```

Same for all the methods. That's it!

**EDIT**

You can use ChannelFactory to create the service proxy, instead of inherit ClientBase

```
New ChannelFactory(Of IService)(endpointConfigurationName).CreateChannel()
```

this gives you an "IService" (you must change it to your service interface) channel proxy.